# Why can't my Table View Cell be shown?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I was learning storyboards tutorial, which is mainly about the use of Tab Bar Controller,Navigation Controller,and Table View Controller. The Table View Controller is embedded in the Navigation Controller.

However, when I ran this app,the Table View Cell can not be seen.I've double checked my code,but still couldn't find the reason.Here are two mages of storyboard.
[Document Outline,click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJkrp.png)
[View Controller Scene, here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQy94.png)

Code in ViewController.swift  is here.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct Player
{
    var name:String?
    var game:String?
    var rating:Int

    init(name:String?, game:String?,rating:Int)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.game = game
        self.rating = rating
    }
}

let playersData = [
Player(name: "Bill Evans", game: "TTT", rating: 4),
Player(name: "OD", game: "Spin the Bottle", rating: 5),
Player(name: "DB", game: "Texas Holder", rating: 2)]



class PlayersViewController: UITableViewController {

var players:[Player] = playersData


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return players.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    //This method will check to see if there is an existing cell that can be recycled.If not, it will automatically allocate a prototype cell and return it to you.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PlayerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    let player = players[indexPath.row]as Player
    cell.textLabel?.text = player.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = player.game
    return cell

   }
}
```

Comment: have you set tableview datasource and delegate properly? Select your view controller, and set table's the delegate and data source to your view controller and re-run :)

Comment: Ehh, I have checked tableview datasource and delegate. The problem is in the identity inspector.The custom class should be "PlayersViewController", instead of "UITableViewController".Thank you, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot ("Document Outline"), there is `PlayersViewController` Scene.
But this should be `Players View Controller` (with spaces).

This means that you set `PlayersViewController` as `title` of ViewController.
You should set this as `custom class` for this scene (ViewController).

So your scene is handled by `UITableViewController` which has no data to present, at the moment.

To fix this, select your view controller or scene, go to Identity Inspector and set `PlayersViewController` in `Class` property.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is in the Identity Inspector. I forgot to change it to the PlayersViewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
//register your cell(nib) in viewdidload
let customCellNib: UINib = UINib(nibName:@"nibName", bundle: nil)
yourTableView.registerNib(customCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PlayerCell")
```